# C - fprintf returning Access violation writing location 0x00246D1C

Tags: c

So my fprintf and also my fputs aren't successfully writing in the file that I want. Here is the relevant code, thank you.

```
    void print_stats(double max, double min, double avg, double sum)
    {
        FILE *paid = ("paid.txt", "w");
        //paid = ("paid.txt", "w");

        if (paid == NULL)
            printf("Failed");
        fputs("Test", paid);
        fprintf(paid, "Max: %.2f\nMin: %.2f\nAverage: %.2f\nTotal: %.2f", 
        max, min, avg, sum);
        fclose(paid);

    }
```

Comment: You are not implementing your NULL pointer check correctly.  You are trying to write a string in read only data segment if i had to guess.  you need to call fopen() instead of just () like your doing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never actually opened the file:

```
FILE *paid = ("paid.txt", "w");
```

This evaluates `("paid.txt", "w")` as an expression, with the comma operator discarding the left operand "paid.txt" and evaluating the right operand "w", and then assigning that to `paid`.

You need to call `fopen` here:

```
FILE *paid = fopen("paid.txt", "w");
```

Comment: @RyanM Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: @RyanM in your original code you also should consider what happens if `fopen` returns NULL because the file cannot be opened. It is not going to end well..